# Datatable css not working after accedentally deleting it, and restoring it back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a datatable css for my table and after I accidentally deleted it and restoring it back it is not working, even tho i deleted all cache and also use ctrl+shift+r.

I want it to be back to normal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what makes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would be very helpful if you could edit the question so your code would reproduce your issue if others copy and paste it into their own IDEs, and additionally you should describe explicitly what error messages you're seeing and where. Right now this question needs more details and clarity before it can be answered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.